# ¿Qué significa "alta noche"?

Tags: vocabulario, expresiones, significado

Hoy he visto esta palabra en el libro de Borges, pero no estoy seguro qué significa. `Alta noche` ¿es noche con luna llena o es medianoche o es una noche en la que no se puede ver nada?

Comment: I tried to improve your post by making a couple corrections and adding some formatting. I have to say that I don't understand "noche mediante". Did you mean ["medianoche"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=R3tGnihBrD6HboYOCc)?

Comment: @Diego, yes, it should be "medianoche".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Alta noche** es un equivalente a **Altas horas de la noche**.

En España usamos las expresiones:

> La fiesta duró hasta **altas horas de la noche**

O también

> La fiesta duró hasta **alta noche**

Para referirnos a **muy tarde** (temporalmente hablando). Así pues, en el caso de la noche, estaríamos hablando de las 23:00 o las 24:00 (las 11 o las 12 de la noche).

Esa misma expresión también se usa para la madrugada. Así pues, si decimos

> La fiesta duró hasta **altas horas de la madrugada**

Estaremos diciendo que

> La fiesta duró hasta las 06:00 o las 07:00 (las 6 o las 7 de la madrugada)

Por cierto, en España dividimos el día en aproximadamente las siguientes partes:

- madrugada: de la medianoche (24:00) al amanecer(06:00-07:00)
- mañana: del amanecer (06:00-07:00) al mediodía (12:00)
- tarde: del mediodía (12:00) al atardecer (18:00-19:00)
- noche: del atardecer (18:00-19:00) a la medianoche (24:00)

Comment: So are these ("alta noche" and "altas horas de la noche") equivalent to "the wee hours of the morning"?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Almost. Since "the wee hours of the morning" refers to the early hours of the morning (05:00-06:00), I'd rather say that its equivalent in spanish is "altas horas de la madrugada" or "alta madrugada" (although I never heard this last one) instead of "alta noche" or "altas horas de la noche". Let's recall that "alta noche" or "altas horas de la noche" refers to the span of time between 23:00 and 24:00 (or even 01:00).

Comment: I've always thought of as "the wee hours of the morning" as more like 3 am, 4 am... I can't help thinking about Chuck Berry's song, "The Wee Wee Hours" which makes it sound like the time you get up to visit the restroom (the "wee-wee" hours).

Comment: After checking some places like UrbanDictionary http://es.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wee+hours or YourDictionary http://www.yourdictionary.com/wee-hours I'm getting the impression that "the wee hours" refers to the whole span of time between midnight and dawn, rather than a short and specific span of time around 05:00 or 06:00, as I first posted. So yes, I agree with you @B.ClayShannon

Comment: Yes, "wee" means small, and so 1 am is the weeest, 2 is quite wee, 3 is very wee, 4 is somewhat wee, and so on.

Comment: @BClayShannon it's like high noon in English — but the opposite

Answer (score 4):

Borges usa esa expresión por lo menos dos veces. Una es en el poema "La Rosa", donde dice:

> la del negro jardín de la **alta noche**

y en el relato "Tlön, Uqbar, Orbis Tertius", donde dice:

> Bioy Casares había cenado conmigo esa noche y nos demoró una vasta
>   polémica sobre la ejecución de una novela en primera persona, cuyo
>   narrador omitiera o desfigurara los hechos e incurriera en diversas
>   contradicciones, que permitieran a unos pocos lectores -a muy pocos
>   lectores- la adivinación de una realidad atroz o banal. Desde el fondo
>   remoto del corredor, el espejo nos acechaba. Descubrimos (en la **alta
>   noche** ese descubrimiento es inevitable) que los espejos tienen algo
>   monstruoso.

En ambos casos hay un contexto de nocturnidad ("negro jardín" en el primer caso, la polémica de sobremesa luego de la cena "esa noche") que remite a horas avanzadas de la noche.

Respecto de las tres opciones de la pregunta. No sería ninguna:

- noche con luna llena: no, porque la expresión no tiene relación con
  la presencia o no de la luna, y eventualmente se referiría al caso de
  luna nueva pues habría mayor oscuridad
- noche mediante: no conozco esa
  expresión; si fuese medianoche, no necesariamente porque pasada la
  medianoche también sería considerable alta noche (mientras falten
  varias horas para la madrugada)
- una noche en la que no se puede ver
  nada: podría ser, pero para ese caso se suele utilizar más la
  expresión ***noche cerrada***

Answer (score 3):

En el español moderno de Argentina, el adjetivo "alta" es utilizado por un sector social para denotar énfasis positivo. En ese sentido, "alta noche" podría ser interpretado como "una gran noche". En el siguiente ejemplo:

> Eh, amigo, alta yantas.

Un individuo le festeja a otro sus zapatillas ("yantas" es equivalente a "zapatillas").

Comment: Por suerte no lo veo a Borges diciendo "Alta noche, _ameo_".